# Echoing photo as bytes in php to java app

Tags: java, php

Someone tried to display image as bytes so, Java app can see it? Again this problem. I found this [tutorial](http://blog-en.openalfa.com/how-to-work-with-binary-data-in-php):

```
$fp = fopen("binary-data.dat","rb");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    // Read the file, in chunks of 16 byte
    $data = fread($fp,16);
    $arr = unpack("C*",$data);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        echo " " . $value;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

This is how tutorial suggest me to output data. It outputs something like:

```
 0 0 0 16 144 0 5 0 0 0 0 4 0 48 0 0
 0 176 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 96 0 0 0 0
 0 112 0 0 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Java coder tells that it's wrong. He needs something like:

```
�R�{�,-l�p6���S�%�����J�@���彇sf1ZVĭ��p��A;[�sG`�2��U.Dڳ=��e*�@���ޱ�1�9H�Ӱ5.gS�T�[s4�3ht.����bl�}��G'L���(3N��ҵU6�J�IJ����7+LH��f��n�y<�����]ă�S�`[S�hJ@Q���������iG$S.J��
                 �*�J�Sj�3�r�$6�>T�6^�߯�!�⊌�Q�*ڔ���e*VQam:t�� ������l��\.%����:���۰��;� K<9j\�2�$�U�[ڋ
�sHH��%L�.��-(��XFf��)b�"��-޶�XR9���V���}�)���vi�t7 ������)Eɥ�V%�-�:VnZ^es��VT��J�JTBI7�[��4�9zg⦾�LIM|KRM6@��rr�|�)c���\���q�R���`4
```

I tried to change the parameter of unpack on `H` (it was wrong too).I changed it to `A`. It printed something like he wants, but now he says that there is some newlines there. So now my code looks like:

```
$fp = fopen("/var/www/9292/inputPhoto1.jpg","rb");
$image="";
while (!feof($fp)) {
    // Read the file, in chunks of 16 byte
    $data = fread($fp,16);
    $arr = unpack("A*",$data);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $image.=$value;
    }
}
fclose($fp);
```

But he still says about some newlines. Anyone can explain me how to output bytes properly in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your entire code block with

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');         // Set the correct MIME type
readfile('/var/www/9292/inputPhoto1.jpg');  // Read & output the file directly from disk
```

Comment: I've tried it. The result is like code I've show with a* parameter. But for some reaon it's not readable and it has size 57 k byte, instead of 35. Don't you know what can cause it?

Comment: Are you outputting anything else? And how are you reading the file? Did you save the page output from your browser?

Comment: Well, there is some boundaries but Java coder knows about them.

Comment: Now tester says, that he has found some mistake in his code. I'll mark your answer. It look fine when I test it with Advanced Rest Client

Comment: Anyway your answer give me new knowlege about job I'm doing now.

Comment: Finally, I've used your solution, thanx